# Execute sql file on every startup using liquibase configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I want to create a SQL initialization file to populate test data every time on Spring startup:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 0001
      author: test
      dbms: postgres
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            - relativeToChangelogFile: true
            - path: data.sql
```

Do you know how I can configure it to be executed on every Spring startup?

Comment: If this is for test cases, you could use an in-memory database using hsqldb or h2 which would only exist while the process was running and therefore liquibase would apply all the changesets.  If you're using a persistent database like postgres though, liquibase would only execute changesets that haven't already been executed before.  You might want to use some other mechanism in this case to always execute sql scripts on startup.

Comment: ok, how I can always execute SQL script during startup?

Comment: If this is for populating test data for unit tests, you could use something like dbrider https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following property. Now the specific changeSet will run every time

```
- changeSet:
    runAlways: true
```

https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changeset.html

> **runAlways** Executes the changeset on every run, even if it has been run before.